# How to set to report footer of SSRS to stay at the bottom of the page?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have this report in SSRS which has a footer. But everytime the report only contains a little data, the footer is located at the end of the last line. On the last page, the location of the footer is correct. Can anyone help me with this? Or has anyone experienced the same thing?

If my question or explanation lacks and you need more info, kindly tell me so that I could provide you with it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Looks like you need table footer instead of page footer.

Comment: Hello @OneZeroPundit, I want the footer to remain at the bottom part of the page, whatever the page it is in, and even if the data shown is only 1. Could table footer do that?

Comment: How you are dividing the reports into multiple pages? Can you show your report design.

Comment: hello @OneZeroPundit, it's grouped at the body part based on a certain field. what do you mean by report design? you mean the .rdl file?

Comment: I don't need the entire rdl just the design. Based on your response I am positive you need group footer. But if you can share the design, I can explain it in detail.

Comment: hello @OneZeroPundit, i'm sorry if i can't comprehend well but by design, is it fine if I just give you a screenshot of the design view of the report? i'll try a group footer by the way. thank you very much.

Comment: Yes screenshot of the design view will be helpful. Also give some details about the groupings inside the report.

Answer (score 3):

First I want to point out that despite the footer displaying at the bottom of your table, in the printed version the footer will appear in the correct location. My fix shouldn't mess this up but I recommend you double check if that is important to you.

OK so I know this seems like a ghetto fix but SSRS reports are finicky. This fix will work for multiple tables but will not work for tables with group page breaks (sorry if that is what you are doing).

Pull your footer line down to the bottom of your page. Use your measurements on the side. You will want to subtract the size of your footer and header AND the margins from your page size. Right click outside of the report page in the designer to get to report properties and set your page size and margins (don't go past less than .5" margins if you intend to print this). This will leave your table at the top and the perfect amount of white space for a full page.

Right above your footer, click insert at the top and draw a small horizontal line. Then preview and see how it looks. If that line is on a page all by itself, move everything up a bit. When it shows correct, paint that line white and nobody will be the wiser.

You can repeat this between each table to ensure the white space has a buffer. The tables will eat the white space but if they go to the very end of the page, you will get a blank page in between unfortunately.

That is my ghetto solution to your problem, sir. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a table footer but what you need is a page footer.  If you click near the bottom left edge of the page, you may already see a footer there that you can edit.  If not:

**To add a page header or footer**

1. Open a report. 
   2.On the design surface, right-click the report, point
   to Insert, and then click Header or Footer.

**To configure a page header or footer**
1. On the design surface, right-click the page header or footer.
2. Point to Insert, and then click one of the following items to add it to the header or footer area:
Textbox
Line
Rectangle
Image
3.  Right-click the page header, and then click Header Properties to add borders, background images, or colors, or to adjust the width of the header. Then click OK.
4. Right-click the page footer, and then click Footer Properties to add borders, background images, or colors, or to adjust the width of the footer. Then click OK.

Comment: hello @lethaljd, i'm certain that what i created was a page footer, but unfortunately, it behaves as what I have described above.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this problem myself.

From all I can sort out, you cannot have the "Page Number" Global variable appear at the bottom of a report when in "Interactive View" and on a page that is not fully filled with records* (ie. when viewing the report in web/ReportViewer/SSRS URL-Access format).

You can however, ensure that Page Number displays at the bottom of the page when printed or in any export format by creating sufficient space in the "body" of the report in Design View. Specifically, make the body height great enough to ensure that the Page Number is at the bottom (if printing on 8.5" x 11" paper, make the body 8.5").

I achieved this in Visual Studio 2015/SSRS 2016. I am not sure how this is done in Report Building wizard as I do not use that tool. 'Hope this helps somebody.

*in this case, Page Number displays immediately after the last visible record. If anyone knows a way around the seeming Interactive View limitation described, please do share.